# How to catch a run-time error in c++?

Tags: c++, iostream, cin

I have a problem with being able to take care of run-time errors where the user types in data different than the one expected. For example, an integer is expected, but (maybe) the user enters a string. In my console programs, when this happens, I just get a whole lot of junk printed on my screen, it goes into infinite loop. How can I take care of this, such that an error message is displayed when this happens, instead of the whole program going to trash?

```
int x = 0;
cout << "\n\nEnter a number(1-9): ";
cin >> x;
if(x<1 || x>9)
{
   cout<<"\nThe place you entered is invalid. Please enter the correct place number";
}else{
   cout<<"Correct";
}
```

If i entered a number above than 2^31(i know its the maximum value for int datatype) or a char value it goes into a infinite loop. How can i catch solve this problme

Answer (score 2):

`cin` is a bit weird in that if you try to read data from the user and the type is wrong (for example, you enter a string when an `int` is expected) or the value is illegal (for example, it's too big), `cin` enters a "fail state" and from that point forward will refuse to read any values from the user until you explicitly fix the problem.  Properly reading data from `cin` such that this doesn't happen is a bit tricky, but can be simplified by just writing some nice helper routines once and calling them in your later programs.

For a description of one approach for properly reading data from `cin`, you might want to check out **[these course notes from Stanford's CS106L course](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/course-reader/Ch3_Streams.pdf)** that describe how streams work in C++ and how to properly read and write data.

Hope this helps!